# Best way to remove empty key/value pairs from objects recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

let's say that I have the current data object:

```
const human = {
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  head: {
    rightEye: '',
    leftEye: '',
  }
  limbs: {
    arms: '',
    legs: '',
  }
  somethingElse: '',
}
```

I want to remove every empty key/value pairs. And this part I got it working with the following code:

```
const removeFalsy = (obj) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop) => {
    if (obj[prop]) {
      if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
        newObj[prop] = removeFalsy(obj[prop]);
      } else {
        newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
      }
    }
  });
  return newObj;
};
```

The thing is empty objects still stay in the main object. I want to remove every empty object from inside the main object in order to get the following result:

```
const human = {};
```

In place of my current results:

```
const human = {
  head: {},
  limbs: {},
}
```

What are my best options?

Comment: Just null them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When recursively calling `removeFalsy`, only assign to `newObj` if the result of the recursive call has an object with at least one key:

```js
const removeFalsy = (obj) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop) => {
    if (obj[prop]) {
      if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {

        // change below:
        const nonFalseyVal = removeFalsy(obj[prop]);
        if (Object.keys(nonFalseyVal).length !== 0) {
          newObj[prop] = nonFalseyVal;
        }
        // change above

      } else {
        newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
      }
    }
  });
  return newObj;
};

const human = {
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  head: {
    rightEye: '',
    leftEye: '',
  },
  limbs: {
    arms: '',
    legs: '',
  },
  somethingElse: '',
}
const nonFalsyHuman = removeFalsy(human);
console.log(nonFalsyHuman);
```

Note that it might be more appropriate to use `.reduce`, and you can use `Object.entries` to get the key *and* the value immediately:

```js
const removeFalsy = (obj) => {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
    if (!val) return a;
    if (typeof val === 'object') {
      const nonFalseyVal = removeFalsy(val);
      if (Object.keys(nonFalseyVal).length !== 0) {
        a[key] = nonFalseyVal;
      }
    } else {
      a[key] = obj[key];
    }
    return a;
  }, {});
};

const human = {
  name: '',
  age: 0,
  head: {
    rightEye: '',
    leftEye: '',
  },
  limbs: {
    arms: '',
    legs: '',
  },
  somethingElse: '',
}
const nonFalsyHuman = removeFalsy(human);
console.log(nonFalsyHuman);
```

Comment: The only thing I can say to you is: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make following changes

- Update `if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {` condition where you set value only if the object has some valid keys.
- Update `if (obj[prop]) {` condition to allow other non-falsy values to enter the loop e.g. 0, etc.

```js
const human = {name: '',age: 0,head: {rightEye: '',leftEye: ''},limbs: {arms: '',legs: ''},somethingElse: ''};

const removeFalsy = (obj) => {
  const newObj = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((prop) => {
    if (obj[prop] !== "") {
      if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
        const temp = removeFalsy(obj[prop]);
        if(Object.keys(temp).length) newObj[prop] = temp;
      } else {
        newObj[prop] = obj[prop];
      }
    }
  });
  return newObj;
};

console.log(removeFalsy(human));
```